# Gradle buildConfigField with integer variable

Tags: android, variables, gradle, buildconfig, android-buildconfig

I would like to define a build config filed where I can use a variable defined in the gradle script it self:

```
def someVar = 512
android {
...
    buildConfigField 'int', 'SOME_INT_FIELD',  someVar
}
```

But this produces following error:

> Error:(25, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildConfigField()'
>
> Possible causes:
>
> The project 'PROJECT' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

---

I could use quotes like:

```
def someVar = 0
android {
...
    buildConfigField 'int', 'SOME_INT_FIELD',  '"' + someVar + '"'
}
```

But this comes to a compiler error in **BuildConfig**

```
// Fields from default config.
public static final int SOME_INT_FILED = "512";
```

---

So for now I stay with:

```
def someVar = 0
android {
...
    buildConfigField 'String', 'SOME_INT_FIELD',  '"' + someVar + '"'
}
```

and use it like:

```
final int value = Integer.valueOf(BuildConfig.SOME_INT_FIELD);
```

---

**Does anybody has better solution or do I use buildConfigField wrong?**

*(I also tried using parentheses in combination with any of possibility above.)*

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found a solution, so maybe this answer will help somebody in future.

```
def String globalVersionCode

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.gradle.build"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1"

    globalVersionCode = versionCode
}

buildTypes {
    release {
         buildConfigField ("int", "DatabaseVersion", globalVersionCode)
    }
}
```

And now in java I can get DatabaseVersion variable:

```
public static final int DB_VERSION = BuildConfig.DatabaseVersion;
```

Comment: Thanks, the key is to define the variable as type of 'String', but use 'int' for buildConfigField. That makes any casting and parsing unnecessary. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: don't forget the commas guys

Answer (score 13):

Declaring an `int` field in `build.gradle` should not and does not require parsing at java side.The only mistake in your code was use of double quotes. Correct way is given below-

```
buildConfigField 'int', 'SOME_INT_FIELD', '512'
```

With above in your `build.gradle` file, you can use it simply as an `int` in java code-

```
public static final int SOME_INT_FIELD = BuildConfig.SOME_INT_FIELD;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
int val = 10
buildConfigField 'int', 'SOME_INT_FIELD', val.toString()
```

Answer (score 5):

You may get some reason to use same gradle file and also use in java files.

```
def boolean isMyFlag

compileSdkVersion 30
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.gradle.build"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    buildConfigField 'int', 'Version_code', "3"
    buildConfigField 'String', 'Version_Name', "'0.1'"
    buildConfigField "boolean", "myFlag", "${isMyFlag}"

}
```

And now you can use in java as well as in gradle file too.

```
// Use for Java
if(BuildConfig.myFlag){
    // My logic here;
}
```

and

```
// Use for gradle
if (isMyFlag) {
    implementation 'com.my.dependency.classes:my-module:2.3'
}
```

My solution is works for both place Java and build.gradle files as you may get some logic like this.

Comment: Note that you can also override the default values in `buildTypes` and `productFlavors` blocks. Combined with properties files, this allows you to have consistent build- and run-time configuration.

Answer (score 2):

```
def someVar = 100

buildConfigField 'int', 'SOME_INT_FIELD',  String.valueOf(someVar)
```

I use the above to resolve the question, hope to help you .